# Add a history page & a read/unread tab?

Tags: feature-request

It would be cool if there was a history page on our profile to show the threads we have visited. This would have come in handy the other night while i was browsing through a load of topics, i found one that was useful but forgot to favorite. Next day i went looking for it thought i'd find it easily enough through tags or my chrome history but didnt and im still looking for it!

Another idea is to add an unread tab on the tagged pages.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use your browser history?

I think a complete history will clutter your profile and it will strain the DB.

Comment: true i could use my browser but it would be cool to be able to look back on what i visited a couple of months down the road. It wouldnt exactly be on the profile page but as a link on the profile or somewhere for the logged in user. Just like youtubes history page. I think a read/unread system would compliment it because most of the time i come on here to just read topics and when going through a tag i'd like a way to sort the read and the unread. What do you think?

Comment: @Jonny I think it would be incredibly, prohibitively resource expensive.

Comment: I know this question is old, but @Jonny's statement still rings true. Surprisingly often, I'll vaguely remember useful question/answer/comment, but be unable to find the page. And when I'm researching, I may visit a couple dozen SO pages per day. The ability to narrow full-text search results to my StackOverflow viewing history could be very valuable (heh, why do you think I found and commented on this question? :-)